# Do speeds of if statements in a repetitive loop affect overall performance?

Tags: performance, dynamic, if-statement

If I have code that will take a while to execute, printing out results every iteration will slow down the program a lot. To still receive occasional output to check on the progress of the code, I might have:

```
if (i % 10000 == 0) {
    # print progress here
}
```

Does the if statement checking every time slow it down at all? Should I just not put output and just wait, will that make it noticeably faster at all?

Also, is it faster to do: `(i % 10000 == 0)` or `(i == 10000)`?
Is checking equality or modulus faster?

Comment: That takes about a nanosecond.  Given that you'd want output once a second or so, that statement only your makes your code a billionth slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case, it won't matter at all.

A slightly longer answer: It won't matter unless the loop is run millions of times and the other statement in it is actually less demanding than an `if` statement (for example, a simple multiplication etc.). In that case, you might see a slight performance drop.

Regarding `(i % 10000 == 0)` vs. `(i == 10000)`, the latter is obviously faster, because it only compares, whereas the former possibility does a (fairly costly) modulus and a comparison.

That said, both an `if` statement and a modulus count won't make *any* difference if your loop doesn't take up 90 % of the program's running time. Which usually is the case only at school :). You probably spent a lot more time by asking this question than you would have saved by not printing anything. For development and debugging, this is not a bad way to go.

The golden rule for this kind of decisions:

> Write the most readable and explicit code you can imagine to do the
>   thing you want it to do. If you have a performance problem, look at
>   wrong data structures and algorithmic choices first. If you have done
>   all those and *need* a *really* quick program, profile it to see which
>   part takes most time. After all those, you're allowed to do this kind
>   of low-level guesses.